# ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> convert to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, arraylist

For clarity:

spielbrettUmwandeln : game board convertion

umgewandeltesSpielbrett : converted board

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> spielbrettUmwandeln(ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> spielbrett)
{
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> umgewandeltesSpielbrett = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    // populate strings

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for(String string : umgewandeltesSpielbrett) {
        builder.append(string).append(',');
    }

    if(builder.length() > 0) {
        builder.deleteCharAt(builder.length() - 1);
    }

    System.out.println(builder);
    return umgewandeltesSpielbrett;
}
```

The 2D-`ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>` shall be converted to a 2D-`ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

I searched a long time to realize that but my research didn't help.

Comment: *Hashtag java???*  You've invented a new way to force tags into titles.  Congratulations.

Comment: What should the `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>` have in it? Give an example of input and output.

Comment: Can you not just loop through the list and create a new ArrayList<String> for each ArrayList<Character>? This seems like a **very** simple bit of logic to come up with, unless I have mistaken your aim.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a proposal, assuming your `Character` class has a `toString()` method.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> umgewandeltesSpielbrett = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

// populate strings
for( ArrayList<Character> listIn : spielbrett){
    ArrayList<String> listOut = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Character c : listIn)
       listOut.add(c.toString());
    umgewandeltesSpielbrett.add(listOut);
}
```

If `Character` does not have a toString() method, here's how you could build one (adapt to your needs, obviously):

```
public class Character {
   String firstName;
   String lastName;

   public String toString() {
      return firstName + " " + lastName;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> spielbrettUmwandeln(ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> spielbrett) {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> umgewandeltesSpielbrett = new ArrayList<>();
    for (ArrayList<Character> x : spielbrett) {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Character c : x)
            list.add(Character.toString(c));
        umgewandeltesSpielbrett.add(list);
    }
    return umgewandeltesSpielbrett;
}
```